# PHP and windows scheduled task

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I am using PHP and have set up some Windows scheduled tasks to run .bat files which have something like

```
"C:\PHP\php.exe" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cron\run-me.php"
```

in them. These all work great and I have set the task to run every 30 min. The 'run-me.php' file contains script to check the ending date of records and expire them if the ending date is less than now (there are a lot more functions in the script like sending out emails etc). Again, they all work great.

Because the script only runs every 30 min I would also like the script to be executed when there are visitors on the site, so basically on each page load, check for ending items, expire them, continue loading to keep all records up to date. The reason I execute in windows task is because there may not be any visitors for hours so I need to expire records and send out emails.

Now, the issue I have is that if the windows task is running and a visitor reloads the page, I am experiencing double scripts being executed because I am often receiving double emails with same content.

My Windows task only allows a single instance to be executed and it is force stopped if it runs for longer than 5 min.

My questions are:

1. Can I execute the Windows Schedule task from my PHP script so that only one instance of the same script is executing?
2. I am using MySQL for the DB, should I lock the row so nothing else can perform any actions on it therefore allowing the script that executes first access to the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using transactions should do the trick. However, I suggest that you only do this in cron (or scheduler in windows) even if it means it runs every five minutes.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. Would this mean I remove the user initiated scripts and just run the expire check from scheduler? This would also mean there is a window of 5 min that expired records could be viewed on the site unless I add a WHERE end_date > NOW or something correct? Without knowing too much about the additional configuration, would running the script every 2 min be too much overhead?

Comment: Running every two minutes should be find as long as you don't process loads of data. If it's only looking at few expired once, that should be fine. Also since you filter for expired once as you do on, the records that you have to work with are always limited, so should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like the way to go.